# Is there any react native library that implements this type of bar?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make a bar where user can move the round point to adjust where the video starts. I want to use something like the brightness adjustment in the following image, but I am not sure about the name of this kind of library.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the slider control? Check out https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-slider

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that helped me with getting the name of the library

Comment: If I was able to answer your question, please mark my answer as the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this library seems to have most of the video player related functionality - [React Native Video library](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want something that is more general. Since I am not gonna play the video in this library.

Answer (score 0):

I found this library to be really useful for me at the end.

The usual slider may not work for me since I wanted to have at least two markers on the slider.

https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider